# Unable to click on a toolbar option in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have recorded a script that has a toolbar and when I click on that toolbar, 5 options are coming. Clicking on one of them takes us to a new page. But when I rerun the script, it only clicks on that toolbar and shows the option but does not click on the option "Business Rules Look-up that I have selected. I have used `clickAndWait link=Business Rules Look-up` command to click on this option. But it is not getting clicked.

Comment: can you please add your sample code ?

Comment: open  "link" 
waitForPageToLoad  30000  
select  id=mainform:companyCode  label=CSC (A)
type  id=mainform:userId  rjain67
type  id=mainform:userPassword  rjain67
select  id=mainform:environment  label=PPLDVLB
clickAndWait  id=mainform:loginAction  
waitForPageToLoad  20000  
verifyText  css=span.pagetitle  Detailed Search
click  id=iconform:IconBar_Tools  
pause  4000  
clickAndWait  link=Business Rules Look-up  
waitForPageToLoad  20000  
verifyText  css=span.pagetitle  Compensation Rule Lookup

Comment: focus  id=mainform:search  
clickAndWait  id=mainform:search  
waitForPageToLoad  4000  
verifyText  css=span.pagetitle  Compensation Business Rules
click  css=span.ui-icon.ui-icon-triangle-1-e  
pause  2000  
click  //div[@id='mainform:j_idt63']/h3[3]/span  
pause  2000  
click  //div[@id='mainform:j_idt63']/h3[4]/span  
pause  2000

Comment: click  //div[@id='mainform:j_idt63']/h3[5]/span  
pause  2000  
click  css=span.ui-icon.ui-icon-triangle-1-s  
pause  2000  
clickAndWait  id=iconform:mainIcon  
waitForPageToLoad  20000  
verifyText  css=span.pagetitle  Detailed Search
clickAndWait  id=iconform:logoutIcon

Comment: I hope this might help

Comment: Add in your question .

Comment: My question is that on this command clickAndWait link=Business Rules Look-up ...it is not clicking on this link

Comment: I am not getting its id from Inspect elemt so that is why i have written the whole name Business Rules Look-up which is visible on the page